# Expectation Rule

Tags: probability-theory

How can I express the expectation $E[X(\omega) 1_A(\omega)]$ as an integral with respect to the push forward measure $\mu_X$? $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$. My problem is the indicator function.

Thanks.

Comment: We have $$\mathbf{E}[X \mathbf{1}_A] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[X \mathbf{1}_A\,|\,X]] = \mathbf{E}[X\mathbf{P}(A\,|\,X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathbf{P}(A\,|\,X=x)\,\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x), $$ where $g(x) = \mathbf{P}(A\,|\,X=x)$ is a Borel function such that $\mathbf{P}(A\,|\,X)=g(X)$.

Comment: If I have a different r.v. $Y$ on another probability space but into the same measurable space as $X$, and the image law is also the same: $P(X \in E)=P'(Y \in E)$, can I say that for any $A$ it holds that $E_{P'}[Y1_A]=E_{P}[X1_A]$?

Comment: @lucmobz Certainly not in general. If $X$ and $Y$ are defined on different probability spaces then at least one of the expressions $Y1_A$ and $X1_A$ makes no sense in general.

Comment: And if we assume the underlying measurable space is the same? Thanks.

Comment: Again no. Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. and non-degenerate with mean $0$ and let $A=\{X>0\}$. Then  $EX1_A>0$ and $EY1_A=0$.